# storing selected value and text of dependable dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using dependable drop-down menu to populate the menu.

First Menu is Country and second menu is city. On selecting the country  it auto populates the city.

I am using [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html) tutorial as reference.

I want to store the value and text of selected city as i need it for displaying table based on this.

My First menu is

```
Country :
<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Country--</option>
<?php
include('db.php');
$sql=mysql_query("select id,data from data where weight='1'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
$id=$row['id'];
$data=$row['data'];
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';
} ?>
</select> <br/><br/>
```

This is my second menu. I want to store value of auto populated item. For this I have used on-change event in my drop-down of city menu as

```
<select name="city" class="city" onchange="getselectval(this)">
<option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
```

My getselectval() function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 functionn getselectval(ctrl){
      selectval=ctrl.options[ctrl.selectedIndex].value;
      selecttext=ctrl.options[ctrl.selectedIndex].text;
      alert(selectval);
      alert(selecttext);

 }
<script>
```

After trying this script it alerts value of only selected item in city menu. I am unable to alert the first item which is auto populated . How can I achieve this ?

Any helps are Welcomed .

Comment: Can you make fiddle demo ?

Comment: @Bala I have to loaded menu and submenu from database. By the way I  have given link in my question which I have used as reference

Comment: @stackuser for the first menu it will be much better to provide rendered HTML (what browser "sees") instead of PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery here using below code -

remove on change function from `select` box

```
<select name="city" class="city">
  <option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
```

bind change event to select box using jQuery and get selected option text and value

```
$(function(){
  $('select[name=city]').on("change",function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
   alert(value);
   alert(text);
  });
});
```

Comment: I trie'd using your code but it didn't gave any item in my second menu i.e.city.

Comment: @stackuser there is no "second menu" in your provided HTML. [Fiddle with this code](http://jsfiddle.net/wq0gwvag/)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Code](http://jsfiddle.net/ParthAkbari/pqhqqhLm/1/)

**only HTML** get JS from JSfiddle

```
<form id="dropdowns" action="index.html">
<label>Country:</label>
<select id="country" name="country">
    <option value="000">-Select Country-</option>
</select>
<br />
<label>State:</label>
<select id="state" name="network">
    <option value="000">-Select State-</option>
</select>
<br />
<label>City:</label>
<select id="model" name="model">
    <option value="000">-Select City-</option>
</select>
<br />
```